# How to resolve Could not start a new session? UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, android, chromedriver, mobile-automation

I am trying to launch mobile browser and getting:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException
>
> Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Do you faced this or any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Have you already looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942950/unreachable-browser-exception-with-appium

Comment: yes, seen. even few more too. Doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you are using appium server with Appium application.

Solution:

1. Open Appium.exe
2. Go to settings and click on it.
3. Select "Over ride existing sessions" and click on it.

Bingo you are done.